# I need to use the beans created in a jar file to be used in my main application. I tried auto-wiring it but I am getting null object

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans, spring-boot-starter

I have a ID Generator application which will be packaged as a Jar, I have some beans created which needs to be used in my Main application. I am not able to inject the beans from my Jar into my main application. Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to declare the bean in your Main application in a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyBean myBean {
        return new MyBean();
   }

}
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

   @Bean
   public MyBean myBean {
        return new MyBean();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( MyApplication.class, args );
   }

}
```

Now MyBean can be autowired in as a dependency.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   MyBean myBean;

}
```